# Finding newest written/modified files

Tags: windows

I was using my (Windows XP) computer which has 2.49 GB free space, and the only thing I was doing was browsing the web. A few minutes later, I got a notification that I was running out of space, which when I check was about 89 MB.

Is there any way to easily find the most recently written/modified files so I can know where all that space went to?

Comment: From @BrettChapman: Try [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/), which worked for me and should still work fine for XP.

Comment: @fixer1234: yes, it is compatible with Windows XP. But its main task is to show you where the big files are.

Comment: You might want to find wasted space, so Windirstat as mentioned by fixer1234 is a good way to go. To free some space you might consider transparently compressing some directories which contain files you still need (this won't delete files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [use Windows search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308895) for files newer than a specific date, or between certain dates.

You should first right-click on your C: drive in Windows explorer and perform disk cleanup, though. Likely you have GB of files in your Recycle Bin and other places. You can also use your browser to clear its cache.

Comment: Already ran disk cleanup, and it only cleared about 100 MB. how do you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Strangely enough, My computer now shows 1.92 GB of free space. Any clue what's going on?

Comment: Some browsers will automatically delete files from the cache if it exceeds a certain size. Do a web search for your browser (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer) and "empty cache".